# How to filter an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, filter

I've this 2D array of data (let's call the variable `arr`) that represents a table with various fields:

```
     [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   
[1],Fruit,Apple,Red,10  
[2],Fruit,Apple,Green,20  
[3],Berry,Strawberries,Red,5  
[4],Tuber,Potato,Yellow,2
```

In this case I need to filter the `arr` variable by column 3 = Red (I don't want to search Red in all the table, just in column 3) obtaining this:

```
    [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   
[1],Fruit,Apple,Red,10  
[2],Berry,Strawberries,Red,5
```

How is it possible to apply the .filter function to a 2D array in order to filter for a single field/column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### ECMAScript 6

```
let filtered = arr.filter(dataRow => dataRow[2] === 'Red');
```

As noted by @ozeebee, ES6 is currently not supported in Google App Scripts, so you should try the following:

#### ECMAScript 5

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function (dataRow) {
  return dataRow[2] === 'Red';
});
```

In the comments, “classic way” refers to the ES5 method.

### Explanation

`.filter` function takes a single parameter which is a callback to a function that returns `true` if array entry should remain or `false` if it should be removed, that’s the filtering. In this case, we should check whether third column of table row equals to `Red`. The code: `return dataRow[2] === 'Red'` is equal to:

```
if (dataRow[2] === 'Red') {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Because the result of comparison is a boolean.

#### See also

- [Array.prototype.filter at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Got it, now it works.  i was not knowing that for javascript the column of a table are considered dataRow

Comment: It's not a JavaScript thing. I chose such name because it's relatively self-descriptive (row of data table).

Comment: For array `[[null, null, new Date()], [null, null, new Date('2015-01-01')]]` it works… Have you passed correct index (2)?

Comment: i've written this code:                                                                                var  filtered = arr.filter(function (dataRow) {
  return dataRow[2].getFullYear() === 2016;
});  but the system gives the error "impossibile to find function .getFullYear() in the object

Comment: You've said that you can read correct year using `dataRow[2][2]`, but where's it? If inside `arr.filter(function (dataRow) {…})`, then is `arr` a three-dimensional array (`[[[]]]`)? If not, have you declared `dataRow` earlier?
Does it work if you set `arr` to `[[null, null, new Date()], [null, null, new Date('2015-01-01')]]`?

Comment: Can you log `dataRow[2]` and `typeof dataRow[2]` (maybe `dataRow[2] instanceof Date` if Logger doesn't tell it otherwise)?

Comment: If I Logger.log(dataRow[2]); the system tells me that dataRow is undefined (it tells the same for just dataRow, dataRow[1] etc). IDK if it's useful, but if i typeof arr[2][2] i get "object"

Comment: if i instanceof Data arr[2][2] i get "true"

Comment: Have you added that Logger inside the callback function? Eg. `arr.filter(function (dataRow) {Logger.log(dataRow);});`. If so, it shouldn't be `undefined`. Are Google App Scripts run in the browser or on a remote server?

Comment: I wasn't logging inside the callback function...  So, now, typeof dataRow[2] gives me a column of "object", and dataRow[2] instanceof Date gives me a column of "true"

Comment: Note that the first form, "Modern way", does not work with GAS scripts because it doesn't support (yet) the javascript ES6 syntax.
GAS scripts are compiled to java code and run on Google servers.