# Filter multidimensional array by a column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an array that I can filter by in Google Apps Script. This works when the array is made of values I take from the columns using `range.getValues()`, but doesn't work when I create a similar multidimensional array using a loop.

I am trying to create the array myself as opposed to getting it from the sheet as the columns that I want are not consecutive: one is the 10th column, the next is the 1st, the next is the 3rd etc.

This works and returns the full multidimensional range filtered properly:

```
function RunReport(){
  var errorSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var enterpriseSheet = errorSS.getSheetByName('Enterprise');
  var destSheet = errorSS.getSheetByName('TestSheet');
  var sheetData = [];

  sheetData = enterpriseSheet.getRange(1, 1, 2000, 4).getValues();
  var filtered = sheetData.filter(function(dataRow){
    return dataRow[0] === 'Error';
  });
  Logger.log(filtered);
}
```

This 'works' but only returns the first 'column' of the array filtered by the 'Error value' but doesn't return the other parts of the array:

```
function RunReport(){
  var errorSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var enterpriseSheet = errorSS.getSheetByName('Enterprise');
  var destSheet = errorSS.getSheetByName('TestSheet');

  var sheetData = [];

  var col1 = enterpriseSheet.getRange(1, 1, enterpriseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var col2 = enterpriseSheet.getRange(1, 10, enterpriseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var col3 = enterpriseSheet.getRange(1, 2, enterpriseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var col4 = enterpriseSheet.getRange(1, 3, enterpriseSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < col1.length; i++)
  {
    sheetData.push(col1[i],col2[i],col3[i],col4[i]) ;
  }
  var filtered = sheetData.filter(function(dataRow){
    return dataRow[0] === 'Error';
  });
  Logger.log(filtered);
}
```

any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849369/how-to-filter-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You're getting a 2D array.
- You're pushing a four 1D arrays.

#### Solution:

- You need to push 4 elements as a single array.

#### Modified Script:

- `push` a single array with four elements

  ```
  //sheetData.push(col1[i],col2[i],col3[i],col4[i]) ; 
  sheetData.push([col1[i][0],col2[i][0],col3[i][0],col4[i][0]]);
  ```
- Alternatively, You can `splice` everything in col1:

  ```
  //for(i=0 ; i<col1.length ; i++)
  //{ sheetData.push(col1[i],col2[i],col3[i],col4[i]) ;}
  col1.map(function(e,i){
      e.splice(1,0,col2[i][0],col3[i][0],col4[i][0]);
      return e;
  });
  Logger.log(col1);
  ```

#### References:

- [2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515924)
- [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array#Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)